# What does this Naive Bayes code from a textbook represent?

Tags: python, naivebayes

I'm now learning data science from a textbook ([link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.05-naive-bayes.html)), but I don't quite understand what the code is trying to tell.

The code shows how Naive Bayes works but the book doesn't tell what is going on, and not explaining well. 
The part I'm not understanding is the last part. What does the print result represent? 
It seems it is probability but I don't quite get how to look at this.

Why taking the last 8 probabilities? Is there any reason for this?

I changed the code slightly to use it on Spyder so it is different from the link.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
x, y = make_blobs(100, 2, centers=2, random_state=2, cluster_std=1.5)
plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='RdBu')

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(x, y)

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
xnew = [-6, -14] + [14, 18] * rng.rand(2000, 2)
ynew = model.predict(xnew)

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='RdBu')
lim = plt.axis()

plt.scatter(xnew[:, 0], xnew[:, 1], c=ynew, s=20, cmap='RdBu', alpha=0.1)
plt.axis(lim)

yprob = model.predict_proba(xnew)
print(yprob[-8:].round(2))
```

The print result is:

```
[[0.89 0.11]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [0.   1.  ]
 [0.15 0.85]]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of training a model is to predict the probable classification of  of y `(yprob)` into one of the two classes  for a given a value of x.

So first you train the model you generate with `model.fit(x, y)`.

Then with this model you predict the class for y with a `model.predict_proba(xnew)`.

Here you are predicting probability for y falling into one of the two classes `(binary classification)` for 2000 randomly generated values of x. In real world, x comes from real data source.

This line just prints the probability of y class for the last 8 values of x.

`print(yprob[-8:].round(2))`

Note that each of the output is a 2 item list for example - the first output is 
`[0.89 0.11]`. This means that for the given value of x, the probability that it belongs to first class is 89% while it belonging to the second class is just 11% - - both probabilities adding up to 100%

Answer (score 1):

The code workflow is

1. Use the dataset to train the model (Gaussian Naive Bayes)
2. Predict the probability of y falling into classes for 2000 random values of x (estimating the maximum likelihood using the trained model)

All the plots and prints are just for visualizing. It simply represents the probability of y falling into class A and B (results of Step 2) for every event.